# Dilate works fine and erode does not output correctly image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)

{
Mat image = imread("text.tif", 0);
Mat dilate_im = image.clone();
Mat erode_im = image.clone();

if (image.empty())//check if empty
{
    printf("Image is not read! File is probably missing! Press any key to        exim program");//message for error
    waitKey(); //10 second delay for showing message to user
}
else
{

    namedWindow("Original", 1);
    imshow("Original", image);

    dilate(image, dilate_im, Mat());
    erode(image, erode_im, Mat());

    namedWindow("Dilate Image", 1);
    imshow("Dilate Image", dilate_im);

    namedWindow("Erode Image", 1);
    imshow("Erode Image", erode_im);

    waitKey();
}
return 0;
}
```

While the dilate function works and outputs the correctly image, erode does not work and I get only one black image.

This is the output:

[View the output of this program here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdQY8.png)

Can you please help me and explain why the erode function does not work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: the output looks ok to me, the text got eroded and has vanished. You could've used a different input for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling both `erode` and `dilate` methods as:

```
dilate(image, dilate_im, Mat());
erode(image, erode_im, Mat());
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode):

> src – input image; the number of channels can be arbitrary, but the depth should be one of CV_8U, CV_16U, CV_16S, CV_32F` or ``CV_64F.
>
> dst – output image of the same size and type as src.
>
> element – structuring element used for erosion; if element=Mat() , **a 3 x 3 rectangular structuring element is used**.

So unknowingly you are calling both `erode` and `dilate` with a default 3x3 kernel, But in case of erosion, the width of foreground Text seems to be less than 3 pixels, which would over-ridden by black color and hence the black output.

Comment: Hello,

I saw this article:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html
Shouldn't make the letter thiner? In my case it erase them instead of making them thiner. In other words, are you saying that if I use a different mask (and not 3x3) this will word?

Comment: Yeah a custom mask with less than 3x3 may work, not sure though, you need to test it